# How to call different actions in a controller with a button from view?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm using `Html.Beginform` with a submit button in it, I'm sending my model variables to a controller and calling the action which I write in the `Html.Beginform` attribute. I want to do that, when I choose a dropdown select, based on this I want to call different actions.

For example when I select apple from dropdown, I want to my button to call actino method `Apple`, when I choose cherry, I want to my button to call action method `Cherry`. Is this possible? Thanks for answers.

Comment: You would have to dynamically change the attribute on the form tag with Javascript to specify a different URL to post to and therefore a different action to call. I do not believe you can make Html.BeginForm change dynamically based client selection of a drop down list since the tag has already been rendered.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to call Apple when someone selects Apple from the `dropdown` and Cherry when someone selects Cherry from the `dropdown`.

Pretty simple and straight forward approach would be to use JavaScript/jQuery to dynamically change the action of the form. Bind the jquery change event for the dropdown:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mySelectElementId').on('change', function() { 
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        if(selectedValue == 'apple'){
            $('#myform').attr('action', '/ControllerName/Apple')
        } else if(selectedValue == 'cherry'){
            $('#myform').attr('action', '/ControllerName/Cherry')
        }
    });
});
```